# Displaying random product in Magento homepage

Tags: php, magento

I added a yes/no attribute on my products which would allow me to display recommended products (attribute is set to yes), on the front page. Now, I want to display 1 random product in my homepage. This is my code right now:

```
    $show_num_items = 2;
$show_index_array = array();
$index_iterator = 1;

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable');

if($_productCollection->getSize()):
    $show_index_array = range(0,($_productCollection->getSize()-1));
    shuffle($show_index_array);
    $show_index_array = array_slice($show_index_array, 0, $show_num_items);

    foreach($_productCollection as $_product):
        $_recommended = $_product->getData('recommend_product');
        if($_recommended == 1): 
            if(in_array($index_iterator, $show_index_array)): ?>
                <div><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'); ?>" />      
                </div>
                <dl>
                    <dt><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a></dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('short_description')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?></dd>
                    <dd><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>">Read More</a></dd>
                </dl>
            <?php endif;
                $index_iterator++;
        endif;
    endforeach;
endif;
```

It's not that clean I know, it works but there are instances in which it doesn't return any products and instances in which it returns 2. How can I make this return 1 product at all times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `$show_num_items = 1;` and `$index_iterator = 0;`, and add `->addAttributeToFilter('recommend_product', 1);` to your collection

Comment: Actually, that was what I did originally but no products showed up so I tried changing the values

Comment: Didn't notice that you were testing if the products were recommended after the collection is loaded. This way, the randomly choosen product may not be recommended, and therefore nothing could be displayed. I've edited my answer accordingly